# The Android and iOS versions of a Facebook game are not launched when visiting the latter on a mobile device

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, air

I have [a small Facebook game](https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/video-preferans), for which there are also free [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/video-preferans/id578738911?mt=8) and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.de.preferans) versions (both created with Adobe AIR) available.

In the [Facebook application settings](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) I have entered the following data:

[image: screenshot]

**My problem:** when you visit popular Facebook games like "Candy Crash Saga" or "Diamond dash" on a mobile device (like iPhone, iPad, Android) then the corresponding app or the corresponding "install app page" in Apple App Store or Google Play is being launched.

However in my case it doesn't happen, why?

The Android error message in German below says: the game is not available for your mobile phone.

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: You need to set "Facebook Login" and "Deep Linking" to be true for both Android and iOS. For Android, you also need to specify a (fully qualified) Class Name that can launch your app.

Comment: The problem is that for my Flex mobile app I do not know a "Class Name". And also, while I offer Facebook login in both iOS and Android versions of my game, I don't use the official Facebook SDKs